# Django Error: NameError name 'db_table' is not defined

Tags: python, django

so I am getting this error in cmd when I try to make migrations. Here is my code:

```
from django.db import models
from shop.models import Product

class Cart(models.Model):
    cart_id = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank = True)
    date_added = models.DateField(auto_now_add = True)
    class Meta:
        db_table - 'Cart'
        ordering = ['date_added']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.cart_id

class CartItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'CartItem'

    def sub_total(self):
        return self.product.price * self.quantity

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product
```

This is my models.py file.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the table Cart exists, you should write

```
db_table = 'Cart'
```

Instead of

```
db_table - 'Cart'
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't see that...

Thank you